# Returning an output from a listbox, TKinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create a clock that reacts to time zone inputs from the user, using TKinter. I'm having trouble with the `selectTZ` function in the code. It prints the selected timezone, but when I try to return it and use it in the clock function, it gives an error. Can you help me figure out what the problem is?

```
import datetime
import tkinter
import pytz

# creates the main clock window
mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
mainWindow.geometry('600x300')
mainWindow['pady'] = 8
mainWindow['padx'] = 8

# cnfig rows and columns
mainWindow.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(2, weight=100)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(3, weight=100)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(4, weight=100)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)

# frame for the date and time display
timeDateFrame = tkinter.Frame(mainWindow, relief='sunken', borderwidth=1)
timeDateFrame.grid(row=0, column=2)


def selectTZ(e):
    selection = (TZlist.curselection())
    TZ = TZlist.get(selection)
    TZ = pytz.timezone(TZ)
    print(TZ)


# list of time zones
TZlist = tkinter.Listbox(mainWindow, relief='sunken', borderwidth=1, selectmode='SINGLE', exportselection=False)
for i in pytz.all_timezones:
    TZlist.insert(tkinter.END, i)
TZlist.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ns', rowspan=5)
TZlist.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', selectTZ)



# scrollbar for TZ list
TZscroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(mainWindow, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL, command=TZlist.yview)
TZscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=5, sticky='ns')
TZlist['yscrollcommand'] = TZscroll.set


# creates the time display
def clock():
    timeNow = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%X')
    timeLable = tkinter.Label(timeDateFrame, text=timeNow)
    timeLable.grid(row=0, column=0)
    mainWindow.after(1000, clock)


# create the date display
def date():
    dateNow = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.now(), '%x')
    dateLable = tkinter.Label(timeDateFrame, text=dateNow)
    dateLable.grid(row=1, column=0)
    mainWindow.after(1000, date)


mainWindow.after(1, date)
mainWindow.after(1, clock)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two `StringVar` to update the labels instead of creating two labels every second. To get the current datetime in a specific timezone use `datetime.datetime.now (pytz.timezone ())`:

```
import datetime
import tkinter
import pytz



# creates the main clock window
mainWindow = tkinter.Tk()
mainWindow.geometry('600x300')
mainWindow['pady'] = 8
mainWindow['padx'] = 8


TZ = tkinter.StringVar(mainWindow, pytz.all_timezones[0])
timeNow = tkinter.StringVar(mainWindow)
dateNow = tkinter.StringVar(mainWindow)

# cnfig rows and columns
mainWindow.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(2, weight=100)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(3, weight=100)
mainWindow.columnconfigure(4, weight=100)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
mainWindow.rowconfigure(4, weight=1)


# frame for the date and time display
timeDateFrame = tkinter.Frame(mainWindow, relief='sunken', borderwidth=1)
timeDateFrame.grid(row=0, column=2)
timeLabel = tkinter.Label(timeDateFrame, textvariable=timeNow)
timeLabel.grid(row=0, column=0)
dateLabel = tkinter.Label(timeDateFrame, textvariable=dateNow)
dateLabel.grid(row=1, column=0)


def selectTZ(e):
    selection = (TZlist.curselection())
    TZ.set(TZlist.get(selection))


# list of time zones
TZlist = tkinter.Listbox(mainWindow, relief='sunken', borderwidth=1, selectmode='SINGLE', exportselection=False)
for i in pytz.all_timezones:
    TZlist.insert(tkinter.END, i)
TZlist.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='ns', rowspan=5)
TZlist.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', selectTZ)


# scrollbar for TZ list
TZscroll = tkinter.Scrollbar(mainWindow, orient=tkinter.VERTICAL, command=TZlist.yview)
TZscroll.grid(row=0, column=1, rowspan=5, sticky='ns')
TZlist['yscrollcommand'] = TZscroll.set


# update date and time
def update():
    dt = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone(TZ.get()))
    timeNow.set(datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, '%X'))
    dateNow.set(datetime.datetime.strftime(dt, '%x'))
    mainWindow.after(1000, update)


mainWindow.after(1, update)
mainWindow.mainloop()
```

[image]